The extremal problem for hexagon ($C_6$) and some graph
I am focusing on the extremal problem in graph theory related to the hexagon $C_6$, as well as the problem of a 6-vertex graph $ H $ that is similar to $C_6 $, where $H $ is a 6-vertex graph consisting of a $ C_4 $ (4-cycle) and a $C_3 $(3-cycle), which share exactly one edge, and then, from the vertex of $C_3 $ that is not part of this shared edge, another edge is branched out.
My Problem
I want to compare the difference between the extremal values of $C_6$ and those of $C_6$ and $H$ (is their difference greater or smaller than 1? When $n$ is sufficiently large). In fact, this involves the extremal problem for the Cartesian product of two $ C_3$'s.
My Try
No matter what, I hope to gather some information about their difference, as this itself is an interesting problem in extremal graph theory. In fact, people have been trying to (completely) determine the extremal graph of $C_6$, but it remains unsolved. I found a few articles on $ C_6 $ on Google, such as 1, but similar articles seem to be quite rare, especially after 2006.
[1]On the Turán Number for the Hexagon
I hope you can provide some information about $C_6$ and its related extremal problems. I look forward to your response.
Below is a rough sketch of $ H $ (since the website doesn't seem to support TikZ, I can only draw it by hand).


Yes. Their difference is much bigger than one for $n$ large. In general, computing the extremal number of bipartite graphs is extremely hard. Not even trees are known. There are a few examples that we do know, we know the extremal numbers for paths, for cycles we know the correct order only for $C_4$, $C_6$ and $C_{10}$. And the correct constant only for $C_4$ if I recall correctly. That being said, we do know all of them are $o(n^2)$ (and this is actually a characterization of bipartite graphs), the celebrated Erdős-Stone theorem states that
$$ex(n,G)=\left(1-\frac1{\chi(G)-1}+o(1)\right)\binom n2$$
In particular, your $H$ is tripartite, so by Erdős-Stone, we have
$$ex(n,H)-ex(n,C_6)=\left(\frac12+o(1)\right)\binom n2$$
Since $C_6$ is bipartite. Which goes to infinity and in particular is bigger than one for $n$ large enough

Thank you for your response. However, the $ H $ I am referring to is not tripartite. Perhaps I did not explain it clearly. It is actually a 6-vertex graph, and I will modify and draw $H $ in the problem.

Additionally, I found an article on geometric polarity in the  reference [1], and I hope that its techniques can be applied to $ H $. Although $ \chi(H) = 4 > 2 $, I still hope to use these methods to derive the upper or lower bounds for the extremal points of $ H $.

@Tommk it is tripartite. It can't be bipartite cause it has a triangle, and you can color the $C_4$ as $1,2,1,2$ then the last vertex of the triangle with color $3$ and the vertex sticking out with color $1$

@Tommk that also implies that you already know the extremal number of $H$ (asymptotically)

You are right, thanks. What I want to know, however, is the difference between $ex(n, {C_6, H})$ and $ex(n, C_6)$

@Tommk Oh! I see, that's a much tighter problem, since they're both $o(n^2)$. I'll think about it

thank you, I think this degenerate extremal problem is quite challenging.
